# Authentication with hapi-auth-cookie not setting session

Tags: node.js, authentication, cookies, hapi.js

I'm trying to set up a simple authentication with Hapijs and its plugin hapi-auth-cookie, but even though the login seems to be successful (right now it's a mock login), when I try to access other endpoints of the API, I'm still getting unauthorized exception.

Here's my server:

```
server.register([inert, auth], function(err){
  server.auth.strategy('base', 'cookie', {
    password: 'supersecretpassword', // cookie secret
    cookie: 'app-cookie', // Cookie name
    ttl: 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 // Set session to 1 day
  });

  server.auth.default({
    strategy: 'base'
  });

    server.route(routes.endpoints);
    //Start the server
    server.start(function () {
        console.log('Server running at:', server.info.uri);
    });
});
```

And here are my login and logout functions:

```
exports.login = {
    auth: false,
    validate: {
      payload: {
        email: joi.string().email().required(),
        password: joi.string().min(2).max(200).required()
      }
    },
    handler: function(request, reply) {
        if(request.payload.email === 'guest@guest.com' && request.payload.password === 'password') {
          request.auth.session.set({id: 123, email: 'guest@guest.com'});
          return reply('Login Successful');
        } else {
          return reply(boom.unauthorized('Bad email or password'));
        }
  }
};

exports.logout = {
    auth: false,
    handler: function(request, reply) {
      request.auth.session.clear();
      return reply('Logout Successful!');
    }
  };
```

When I hit the login endpoint, it replies with the "Login Successful" message but, as I said, can't access other endpoints that don't have "auth: false" within its config.

Any help will be deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First check if the cookie is created on the browser. After this try to set the auth object like this:

```
auth: {mode:'required',strategy:'base'}
```

Other modes are: **try, optional**. Set optional if it doesn't matters if user is authenticated or not. Set **required** to the endpoints you want only to be accessed by authenticated users.

If you want to secure routes by user roles, you will need to set a scope attribute to the user object set on the session:

```
request.auth.session.set({id: 123, email: 'guest@guest.com', scope:'admin'});
```

later on the auth object of the routes you set the scopes:

```
auth: {scope: ['admin']}
```

also set `isSecure: false` when you create the strategy. This way the cookie is sent to the client.